# Java - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, runtime-error

I am working on a java program that generates random numbers and then puts them in an array. Then the program is supposed to go through the array, put the even and the odd numbers in two new arrays, and present them to the user. The program also tells the user how many odd and even numbers there are in the array.

I get "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" when trying to compile this code.
Can someone tell me why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
class Randomnumbers
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )

    {

        Random random;
        int i;
        int numberOfNumbers=0;
        int upperRange=999;
        int lowerRange=0;
        int randomNumber=0;
        int even=0;
        int odd=0;
        int currentOdd=0;
        int currentEven=0;
        int[] oddNumbers=new int[0];
        int[] evenNumbers=new int[0];

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter how many random numbers you want(0-999)");
        numberOfNumbers=in.nextInt(); 

        int[] numbers=new int[numberOfNumbers];


        random = new Random();

        for (i = 0; i < numbers .length; i++){

            randomNumber = random.nextInt(upperRange-lowerRange) + lowerRange;
            numbers[i] = randomNumber;

        }      

        System.out.println("\n" +"These are the random numbers:");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));

        for(i=0; i < numbers .length; i++){

            if((numbers[i] % 2) == 0)
            {
                even = even + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                odd = odd + 1;
            }


        }

        evenNumbers=new int[even];
        oddNumbers=new int[odd];

        for(i=0; i < numbers .length; i++){

            if((numbers[i] % 2) == 0)
            {
                evenNumbers[i]=numbers[i];        
            }
            else
            {

                // this is the code line the compiler does not like:
                oddNumbers[i]=numbers[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The following " +even +" numbers are even:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(evenNumbers));
        System.out.println("The following " +odd +" numbers are odd:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(oddNumbers));   

    }
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace. However, you are running your loop to insert the even/odd numbers into their arrays as `i < numbers.length`, but you are using arrays `evenNumbers` and `oddNumbers`. What is the likelihood that these two arrays have the same length as your original numbers array?

Comment: Compiler cannot be complaining if its an exception

Comment: This wont even compile: for (i = 0; i < numbers .length; i++){

Comment: Hi @KevinO and thank you for your answer. I am not sure I understand what you mean. I want the program to loop and fill the arrays with even and odd numbers until it reaches the end of the original array containing all the random numbers

Comment: Hi @pczeus. The program actually compiles, generates the random numbers, presents them but then breaks when it is supposed to present the odd and even numbers.

Comment: @Emil, I understand your intention. However, let us assume there are 11 random numbers. Of those, 5 are even and 6 are odd. You therefore create `evenNumbers = new int[5]; oddNumbers = new int[6];` based upon the numbers. But you then run the loop from 0..10, so you will attempt to assign at some point, e.g., evenNumbers[6] = X, and that is larger than the number of elements in the evenNumbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really not a good practice to run through the loop multiple times.

I would the code to only traverse the random array a single time.

```
List<Integer> evenNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> oddNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
  if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
    evenNumbers.add(numbers[i]);
  }
  else {
     oddNumbers.add(numbers[i]);
  }
}
```

You can get the total number of evens/odds from the size of the respective `List`s, and you can print them out, iterate them, etc.

Of course, this approach assumes you can actually use Java objects as opposed to merely arrays.

If you must use arrays, then change the final part of the code to after the allocation for the evenNumbers and oddNumbers arrays to:

```
int evenIdx = 0; 
int oddIdx = 0;

for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
  if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
    evenNumbers[evenIdx++] = numbers[i];
  }
  else {
    oddNumbers[oddIdx++] = numbers[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a nice solution @KevinO. But this is a school assignment and I am not supposed to use ArrayList :)

Comment: @Emil, added an array only approach.

Comment: Wow @KevinO. That actually worked exactly the way I wanted it to. Brilliant - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
oddNumbers[i]=numbers[i];
```

Because: the number of elements in `oddNumbers` is not the same as `numbers`

When you use the index `i` to access the element in the array `number`, you accidentally, try to access the `i^th` element in the `oddNumber` that causes `ArrayIndexOutOfBound`.

Fix: At least, make sure the index `i< oddNumber.length` and `i< numbers.length`

For example

```
for(i=0; i <numbers .length && i<oddNumbers.length; i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem statements are below. Depending on the random numbers generated either of the statements will result in `ArrayIndexOutBoundsException`.

```
evenNumbers[i]=numbers[i];
oddNumbers[i]=numbers[i];
```

Here are some of the options to resolve this:

1. Maintain separate indexes for evenNumbers and oddNumbers in

   ```
       for(i=0; i < numbers.length; i++){
       if((numbers[i] % 2) == 0)
       {
           evenNumbers[eIndex++] = numbers[i];
       }
       else
       {
           oddNumbers[oIndex++] = numbers[i];
       }

   }
   ```
2. Use `List<Integer>` for oddNumbers & evenNumbers.

   ```
   List<Integer> oddNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   List<Integer> evenNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();


   for(i=0; i < numbers.length; i++){

       if((numbers[i] % 2) == 0)
       {
           evenNumbers.add(numbers[i]);
       }
       else{
           oddNumbers.add(numbers[i]);
       }
   }
   ```